# Original English expressions for "raison d’être" and "joie de vivre"

Tags: phrase-requests, loanwords, french

I know that the two phrases have been adopted into the English lexicon, but *raison d’être* and *joie de vivre* are phrases, not words.  As phrases, they certainly sound better in French than would their literal translation to English.

Are there any "more English" words or expressions for the same concepts?

If not, doesn't that seem odd, or is it common enough for even borrowed phrases to supplant the development of a native term?

(Further, it seems a little conspicuous that a language would lack native terms for such core concepts of the human experience!)

Comment: Can you try to explain what they each convey? A lot of us aren't native French speakers.

Comment: You're not likely to get much more than near-literal translations. I would be so bold as to posit that the reason why many of these *frenchisms* are popular en anglais, is that it just sounds better (or speakers want to be perceived thus) in french. English vernacular is full of stuff like this  -  *Bon ami*, *Je ne sais quoi* e.t.c. , all because they're just not as rich-sounding as similar expressions in English

Comment: @AlexW: You beg the question!  I thought these phrases were as English as other French "loan-words" like  _apropos_, _attache_, etc.; and "loan-phrases" like _au contraire_, _a la carte_, _carte blanche_, etc.

Comment: I simply meant to ask if you could explain, in English, a situation where these phrases would be used and what type of sentiment they convey.

Comment: @AlexW do you not have access to a dictionary?

Comment: “If not, doesn't that seem odd, or is it common enough for even borrowed phrases to supplant the development of a native term?” — Quite the contrary. The textbook situation where loan words are adopted is _when there is no native word for the concept_. So if there is no ‘Englisher’ word for these things, it doesn’t necessarily mean the French ones had supplanted the English ones; it might just as well mean that the lack of native English words is exactly why the French ones were borrowed to begin with.

Comment: English has "reason for existence" and "joy of living" -- perfectly fine phrases.  It's just that the French terms have  a certain je ne sais quoi.

Comment: (In other words, these phrases are not used because the associated concepts cannot be as efficiently expressed in English.  Rather, they are used because French phrases sound high-brow.)

Comment: They have been in the English lexicon longer than 'internet' and 'selfie'. Perhaps when they become fossilised, someone will ask 'Can't we borrow words from a different language to rekindle their zestiness?'

Comment: What a reflection of the Zeitgeist this discussion is! Leave it open; it is a reasonable question about English expression of concisely expressed concepts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We can trace most English words back to a time they were *[borrowed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_English_words_by_country_or_language_of_origin)* from another language:

[image]
<sub>*Image from Wikipedia.org*</sub>

The expressions *[raison d'etre](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=raison%20d%27etre&searchmode=none)* and *[joie de vivre](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=joie%20de%20vivre&searchmode=none)*, are relatively recent, acquisitions:

> *raison d'etre* (n.)
>
> "excuse for being," 1864, first recorded in letter of J.S. Mill,
> ***from***
> French raison d'être, literally "rational grounds for existence."
>
> *joie de vivre* (n.)
>
> 1889, ***French***, literally "joy of living."
>
> *<sub>etymonline.com **emphasis** added</sub>*

I might add that the acquisition of *joie de vivre* seems incomplete, as the etymology lists it as ***French***, rather than ***from*** French. It seems to have a reasonable chance of making a complete entry into English eventually, since we have always been quite hospitable toward elegant French expressions. I still italicize *joie de vivre* as a foreign expression in my writing, but it seems common enough that some might consider it pure English.

---

As a reasonable **intersection** of the two French phrases, I like *[life force](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/life+force)*:

> noun
>
> The vital principle or animating force within living beings:
>
> *<sub>The American Heritage® Roget's Thesaurus.</sub>*

The ***rational basis*** of our existence as living things is some *life force* that we do not yet fully understand, and **joy** seems to be a particularly meaningful expression of our *life force*.

---

Some may complain that the word *[force](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=force&allowed_in_frame=0)* is still too French, because it was borrowed from Old French, but it was actually quite a long time ago:

> c. 1300, "physical strength,"
> ***from Old French*** force "force, strength;
> courage, fortitude; violence, power, compulsion" (12c.),
> from Vulgar
> Latin *fortia (source also of Old Spanish forzo, Spanish fuerza,
> Italian forza),
> noun use of neuter plural of Latin fortis "strong,
> mighty; firm, steadfast; brave, bold" (see fort).
>
> *<sub>etymonline.com **emphasis** added</sub>*

If we concede to the objections against *force*, we can still be satisfied with plain old *[life](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=life&allowed_in_frame=0)*, which is about as English as any English word can get:

> **Old English** life (dative lif) "existence, lifetime, way of life,
> condition of being a living thing, opposite of death,"
> from
> Proto-Germanic *libam
> (cognates: Old Norse lif "life, body," Dutch
> lijf "body," Old High German lib "life," German Leib "body"), properly
> "continuance, perseverance,"
> from PIE *leip- "to remain, persevere,
> continue; stick, adhere" (see leave (v.)).
>
> Much of the modern range of meanings was ***present in Old English***.
> Meaning "property which
> distinguishes living from non-living matter" is from 1560s.
> Sense of
> "vitality, energy" is from 1580s.
> Extended 1703 to "term of duration
> (of inanimate objects)."
>
> *<sub>etymonline.com **emphasis** added</sub>*

*Language is my **life**.* Meaning: *Language is my **conscious rationale** to work another day, and the deepest **joy** of my heart.*

Comment: See also [this](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/joie): (for _joie de vivre_) "General feeling of well-being, total contentment arising from the simple fact of existing" (my translation). "_Il s'agissait [dans les Noces de Cana] (...) de montrer la force, la santé, et la joie de vivre dans des visages radieux, exempts d'inquiétude, et des corps robustement superbes_ (Gautier, Guide Louvre, 1872, p. 40).". In an American movie a character said something along the lines of "_you're messing with my Qi_"; sometimes I feel "joie de vivre" is used like that in English, more so than with Fr.. Thanks.

Comment: [*Qi*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qi) is the Chinese analogy to *life force*!

Comment: Your first sentence says something I don’t believe you intended for it to say … (Also, I don’t believe it’s really important whether there is a _from_ or not—there isn’t in _joie de vivre_ because the English is precisely the same as the French source. In _raison d’etre_, the Anglicising got rid of the cirucmflex, so it’s _from_ or _based on_ French _raison d’être_, but it isn’t quite the same.)

Comment: Thanks, @JanusBahsJacquet. Perhaps I use *borrowed* too broadly in that first sentence? For some words it might be better to say that their roots were borrowed. Good point about the distinction of the anglicized spelling. Perhaps, my foolish consistency really is a conservative hobgoblin.

Comment: It was more that there are quite a lot of English words that were actually _not_ borrowed at any time, but are directly inherited in a straight line, at least as far back as Proto-Indo-European. :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I accept the view of ancient language as "independent streams," and PGmc had the broadest, deepest and most powerful influence on Old English, so it is often helpful to view it as a straight line. Three factors moderate this view: 1. PGmc was never homogeneous. 2. It "borrowed" from other PIE based languages. 3. Most English expressions "borrowed" since OE, also trace to PIE with analogous Germanic cognates. Heretical as it seems, a straight line through Germanic stock is an **arbitrary** designation of English, which "borrowed" **more** from PGmc than any other source ;-)

Comment: @ScotM 1. PGmc was probably quite homogeneous at some point: it obviously developed far and wide, but at the starting point when it first separated itself enough to be a thing of its own, it must have been quite homogeneous. 2. Yes, all IE languages have borrowed exstensively from their neighbours (most of which have been IE also). 3. There are lots of English borrowings that have analogous Germanic cognates, yes. But there are also lots of words which have not at any point since PIE been borrowed in any ancestral stage of what is now English from any other language: they are purely inherited.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet and ScotM: I am dying to see your arguments in more detail.  Could you elaborate at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251687/did-english-borrow-or-inherit-from-proto-germanic-pgmc ?

Comment: Bravo, @feetwet!  I'm not sure if that might be too broad a topic for ELL, but I think it would work on [Linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/). I actually agree with Janus completely, with the reservation that in **some conversations** (like this one) it is helpful to view the relationship between languages as an interrelated network rather than independent streams.

Comment: You gave as an answer to the OP a word for a _combination_ of two different French phrases. Do you have any suggestions for the two separately?

Comment: I like your's @Mitch! We were both driving at the same concept of "borrowing" at the heart of the question, and I thoroughly enjoyed your tack :-)

Comment: this answer has a lot of joie de vivre, but you seemed to completely forget the raison d'etre of the OP, Scott  :O

Answer (score 15):

For 'joie de vivre' I suggest

- elan
- panache

For 'raison d'etre', I suggest

- essence
- rationale

These were chosen ironically because you requested something English, which all of these are, and yet your hidden intention was that they be more ... Anglo-Saxon, which these are all not. You've kind of hit a bunch of issues here: translation (how exact must it be), when is a word English vs foreign (when you can tell or when everyone knows what it means), single words vs phrases (why must a single word be necessary? Because often they exist).

So in the end I think it is safe to say that really for what you intend there are no such words, but all of the suggestions, as much as they get close to the meaning, are literally English now.

Comment: I bet you like Italian operas too.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ha ha! No.

Comment: I wish in cases like this the OP could designate a "**tl;dr answer**," because **this is it**!

Comment: hilarious answer, Mitch

Answer (score 5):

[Essence](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/raison-d%27%C3%AAtre?q=raison%20d%27%C3%AAtre), [Lifeblood](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lifeblood), [Be-all and end-all](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/be-all%20and%20end-all):

> Cooking is my raison d'etre
>   Cooking is my *essence*.
>   Cooking is my *lifeblood*.
>   His work was the be-all and end-all of his existence.

However the latter (taken from the link) doesn't always sound good.

Comment: "lifeblood"... very nice.

Answer (score 4):

The phrase *raison d'etre* is very commonly used in English as "reason for being".  Example: *John saw writing novels as his reason for being.*

There is no specific phrase I am aware of which captures the full meaning of *joie de vivre*, leaving the method of expression up to the writer rather than having a set phrase.

Comment: Perhaps also consider "reason for existence" for _raison d'etre_.

Comment: How is "joy of living" not a "specific" English phrase?

Comment: @HotLicks - In literature, usually the French is used directly.  If you switch it to "Joy of living" in those instances, it almost always sounds awkward, because the way the phrase is used in French doesn't fit in sentences the same way. For example, this Sylvia Plath quote: "Life has been some combination of fairy-tale coincidence and joie de vivre and shocks of beauty together with some hurtful self-questioning."  If you substitute "joy of living" here, it sounds quite awkward in English -- yet the placement and use is perfect with the French. This applies to most uses in English I've seen.

Comment: @HotLicks -- in these cases, if you wanted to switch to English, you would use one of many other elocutions, such as this paraphrase: "Life has been some combination of fairy-tale coincidence and delight in being alive and shocks of beauty together with some hurtful self-questioning."  This is why I said there is no _specific_ phrase which fully captures the meaning.

Comment: The only reason "joy of living" sounds strange coming from Sylvia Plath is because you expect her to say "joie de vivre".

Comment: @HotLicks Exactly.  Because the exact English word translation doesn't capture the full sense of meaning as the French, which is why it is an inadequate translation.

Comment: So anything that isn't French is inadequate.

Comment: @HotLicks No, anything that would use one or more of the shades of meaning of _joie de vivre_  in English requires an author to use a creative elocution that fully carries their meaning, rather than there being one fixed phrase -- since their isn't one that fully matches in English for all possible derivations.  In a few cases, that will be "joy of living" and in many more it will be something else.

Comment: Except that the particular English phrase chosen might very well express the *exact* "shade" of meaning intended by the author, vs leaving his reader to guess which was intended.

Answer (score 4):

"joie de vivre" synonyms include:

- zest
- enthusiasm
- fire
- gusto
- zeal
- spirit
- verve
- ardour
- vitality

"raison d'être" synonyms include:

- purpose
- mission
- justification
- rationale
- point

As to why one might choose to use a loan word rather than something more English sounding, I'd say fashion. The only loan phrase from French that doesn't have a good English synonym (at least to my mind) is "déjà vu" for that strange sense of having done/seen something before.

Comment: You realize that *gusto* (very Italian sounding) is derived from Italian/Latin, as are *spirit*, *verve*, *ardour* (very French sounding to my ears), and *vitality*. *Enthusiasm* is French, whereas *zeal* is borrowed from Greek. Only *fire* is "English" i.e. West Germanic.

Comment: I'm aware that "gusto" is another loan word.  But honestly, if you're going to limit English to only those words coming from West Germanic sources, you'll eliminate a lot of history. Other that "gusto", I'd say the rest of the words have transformed enough from their sources to no longer be considered loaners.

Comment: Your list is filled with loanwords, some are older than others, but nearly all have become "English" over the years. Who is to say, when an English speaker  will one day  claim, *Joie de vivre* is an English sounding expression. :)

Comment: So your objection is to "English sounding"? I'm fine substituting another phrase but "something borrowed earlier" doesn't really feel right to me. Suggestions?

Comment: I don't think any of those synonyms are sufficiently synonymous.  E.g., I might refer to someone's "enthusiasm for life" instead of "joie de vivre," but none of those synonyms stands on its own as a reasonable substitute for the phrases.

Comment: I think a lot of people are overlooking just how nicely *purpose* fits.

Answer (score 2):

You might use "***obsession***" for "*raison d'etre*".

A common English expression for "*joie de vivre*" is: "***lust for life***".

Comment: Yeah, for Iggy Pop.

Comment: Wish I had read this answer before posting my own, but ya... I was humming Iggy Pop, too!  8D

Comment: And before Iggy Pop there was Kirk Douglas as Vincent van Gogh in [_Lust for Life_](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049456/) (1956). So here's a question that never occurred to me before: When Iggy Pop sings "Of course, I've had it in my ear before" in the lyrics to "Lust for Life," is he making an oblique van Gogh reference?

Answer (score 1):

The expression *joie de vivre* literally means *joy of life*.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I believe the question is asking for an equivalent English expression, not a direct translation.

Comment: Ironically the only correct, non-humorous, answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both “raison d’être” and “joie de vivre” are terrific and perfectly colloquial, but for the fun of it:

*Joie de vivre*:  maybe *lust for life*. Some say *thirst for life* but I like lust.

*Raison d’être*: maybe "It's the reason I get out of bed in the morning." or "Without it I would be lost."